# Enter a code branch every ten percent till 100 percent

Tags: c#

I can think of some very convoluted methods with loops and nested loops to solve this problem but I'm trying to be more professional than that.

My scenario is that I need to enter a section of code every ten percent but it isn't quite working as expected. It is entering the code about every percent which is due to my code but I lack the knowledge to know how to change it.

```
int currentPercent = Math.Truncate((current * 100M) / total);

//avoid divide by zero error 
if (currentPercent > 0)
{
   if (IsDivisible(100, currentPercent))
   {
     ....my code that works fine other than coming in too many times
   }
 }
```

Helper referenced above where the trouble is:

```
private bool IsDivisible(int x, int y)
{
  return (x % y) == 0;
}
```

So obviously it works as it should. Mod eliminates currentPercent of 3 but 1 & 2 pass when really I don't want a true value until currentPercent = 10 and then not again till 20...etc.

Thank you and my apologies for the elementary question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might misunderstand you, but it seems like you're trying to do something extremely simple more complex than it needs to be. What about this?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        // Here, you can do what you want - this will happen 
        // every ten iterations ("percent")
    }
}
```

Or, if your entire code enters from somewhere else (so no loop in this scope), the important part is the `i % 10 == 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Mod will only catch exact occurrences of your interval.  Try keeping track of your next milestone, you'll be less likely to miss them.

```
const int cycles = 100;
const int interval = 10;
int nextPercent = interval;

for (int index = 0; index <= cycles; index++)
{
    int currentPercent = (index * 100) / cycles;
    if (currentPercent >= nextPercent)
    {
        nextPercent = currentPercent - (currentPercent % interval) + interval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (IsDivisible(100, currentPercent))
   {
     ....my code that works fine other than coming in too many times
   }
```

try changing that 100 to a 10. And I think your x and y are also backwards.

You can try a few sample operations using google calculator.

(20 mod 10) = 0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand, but I think this is what you want? You also reversed the order of modulo in your code (100 mod percent, rather than the other way around):

```
int currentPercent = current * 100 / total;

if (currentPercent % 10 == 0)
{
    // your code here, every 10%, starting at 0%
}
```

Note that code this way only works properly if you are guaranteed to hit every percentage-mark. If you could, say, skip from 19% to 21% then you'll need to keep track of which percentage the previous time was to see if you went over a 10% mark.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (int percent = 1; percent <= 100; percent++)
{
    if (percent % 10 == 0)
    {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you increment your % value, this may or may not work `% 10 == 0`. For example jumping from 89 to 91 % would effectively skip the code execution. You should store last executed value, 80 in this case. Then check if interval is >= 10, so 90 would work, as well as 91.